# What algorithm can be used to find the optimal solution for this?

Tags: algorithm, theory

I have accounts with positive and negative balance and a pledge relationship between some. A pledge gives accounts with negative balance the right to retrieve money from the pledging account to cover their loss.

I want to find the optimal order of invoking this right of retrieving money.

```
            1    2    3
A 1000 | -1000 -500 -500
B 1000 | -1000
```

In the given example account A and B have a positive balance of 1000 and accounts 1,2,3 are covered by priority (1 > 2 > 3). I want to cover as many accounts as possible by distributing the money of A and B on 1,2,3 while honoring the priority.

In this particular example choosing A1 as my first pair would result in only covering 1000 but if I choose B1, A2, A3 I have the optimal solution of covering 2000.

How is this kind of optimization problem called and what are the algorithms to tackle it?

Comment: You will get more answers if you explain the accounting terminology in your question.  What do *pledging*, *shortfall*, and *covering* mean?

Comment: Perhaps you could find better answers at http://cstheory.stackexchange.com or http://math.stackexchange.com

Comment: I am pretty sure cstheory would be able to answer this easily but this question is not on topic for the site. They want research grade questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's basically a network flow problem. I'll draw the capacitated graph for your example (unlabeled arcs have infinite capacity). `s` is the source and `t` is the sink.

```
     >A------->1
1000/ |\       ^\
   /  | \     /  \1000
  /   |  \   /    \
 /    |   \ /  500 v
s     |    /->2--->t
 \     \  /        ^
  \     \/        /
   \    /\       /500
1000\  /  \     /
     >B    --->3
```

The answer isn't the max flow; it's the flow that maximizes 1, then 2, then 3. One poly-time algorithm is to modify a max flow algorithm based on augmenting paths (simple paths!—otherwise we might take flow away from a higher priority account) preferentially to augment paths via 1, then 2, then 3.

Comment: Looks promising, I will read up on it in my Cormen and mark accepted once I can reproduce it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

My association says you could find info in the area if 'Packing Problems' (applied outside the field of geometry)

Being no expert in the field, I found the following topics that appear relevant:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cutting_stock_problem
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem

perhaps even related:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragmentation_(computer)

Comment: Yes I have the same feeling but would like to find a better match.